# What's the component that controls the lefthand navigation menu on the blueprintjs docs?

Tags: blueprintjs

The nav on the left of the blueprintjs http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core looks like some sort of mashup between blueprint's Menu and Tree components, but also has the neat feature of highlighting what section you're reading as you scroll down the page.

As is tradition with big frameworks, I'd assume the docs are built with the framework it's documenting. Is it a custom component built for the blueprint docs, or is this out of the box and I'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a smallish custom component called NavMenu.

See: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/f565570f6e442a686398ce0c12c7d7afd3dcf006/packages/docs/src/components/navMenu.tsx#L52